# Clicking on a dynamically added span using jQuery - on doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have a `span` which is added dynamically to my page. I want to do some action when clicking the span.

**I have the following HTML**:

```
    <span class="assistly-widget" id="assistly-widget-1">            

<span style="width:65px;display:inline-block;min-height:22px;background: url(http://assets0.assistly.com/images/customer/widget/chat/launch_chat_sprite.png) no-repeat scroll 0 -40px transparent;">&nbsp;

</span></span>
```

**Script on my page**:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('test');

        $(document).on('click', '.assistly-widget span', function () {
            alert('click');
        });
    });
</script>
```

The code which renders the span:

```
         <li>


    <script src="https://d218iqt4mo6adh.cloudfront.net/assets/widget_embed_libraries_191.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script>

      // ********************************************************************************
      // This needs to be placed in the document body where you want the widget to render
      // ********************************************************************************

      new DESK.Widget({
          version: 1,
          site: 'support.saxo.com',
          port: '80',
          type: 'chat',
          displayMode: 1,  //0 for popup, 1 for lightbox
          features: {
              offerAlways: false,
              offerAgentsOnline: false,
              offerRoutingAgentsAvailable: true,
              offerEmailIfChatUnavailable: false
          },
          fields: {
              ticket: {
                  // desc: &#x27;&#x27;,
                  // labels_new: &#x27;&#x27;,
                  // priority: &#x27;&#x27;,
                  // subject: &#x27;&#x27;
              },
              interaction: {
                  // email: &#x27;&#x27;,
                  // name: &#x27;&#x27;
              },
              chat: {
                  //subject: '' 
              },
              customer: {
                  // company: &#x27;&#x27;,
                  // desc: &#x27;&#x27;,
                  // first_name: &#x27;&#x27;,
                  // last_name: &#x27;&#x27;,
                  // locale_code: &#x27;&#x27;,
                  // title: &#x27;&#x27;
              }
          }
      }).render();
    </script>
                        </li>
```

Usually the `.on` works well, but in this case nothing happens. I get the `alert('test')`, but not the `alert('click')`.

Comment: Your delegated selector should work. Check the console for errors elsewhere in the page.

Comment: do you have a jsFiddle for this?

Comment: Whilst it should work and does in an isolated case such as here http://jsfiddle.net/xXCEh/ I would perhaps recommend changing the selector if there is nothing else inside the first span so that you bind to the outer one rather than the inner one. `span.assistly-widget`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write bindings for elements, it finds those elements on the page and bind events on them. As per your approach, it will find for your element on document.ready at which time it is not present.

You can use this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.assistly-widget span', function () {
     alert('click');
 });
```

as said in an earlier answer by Konza. Since it will bind the event on document(which is always present) and will work on all the elements it finds in the document.

Or as you need to bind the event again after the element is added. In order to this this you put your binding events in a function and call that function after your element has been added. So then, it will be able o find your element and bind event on it.

Comment: .on will work even if elements are added later dynamically. There is no need to bind it again.  Please check the docs

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work. Here is the jsFiddle.
  http://jsfiddle.net/shyamchandranmec/xv8Mf/2/

```
 $(document).on('click', '.assistly-widget span', function () {
     alert('click');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try .live instead of .on

```
$(document).live('click', '.assistly-widget span', function () {
            alert('click');
        });
```

Comment: I think .live is deprecated after version 1.7

Comment: Yes, It's deprecated after version 1.7, but you can use .live. For that you have to include one more script provided by jQuery i.e: jQuery Migrate Plugin (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme). With the help of this plugin you still use the deprecated methods from new version of jQuery

Comment: Okay. Good to know that. But they introduced .on() to use instead of .live(). So .on will be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple add span dynamically and give it a name or class and register a live click event for that span.